# Adding a digital signature to a PDF File using Java

Tags: java, pdf, signature, digital

I am looking for a way to generate signatures(like a Physical one) from a Name and surename in the Programme then put it in the PDF file using Java.
I researched but I didnt find what I need().
if someone knows how it works I will be happy if you tell me.
I can do it by adding a font that looks like a signatures but it will not look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question about the appearance of the signature or about having the signature authenticated from an authorized party?

For the first purpose you can use some of the image processing libraries and append the signature as an image, try **jimage** as it has a wide community.

For the second purpose I would recommend **Itext** library, it provides you with techniques to authenticate your signature with your valid certificate.